# Regex parsing a string

Tags: regex, xml-parsing

I want to split a string using regex

**For example:**

```
<event><id>UPDATE_USER_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS_APP</id></event>
```

I want to be able to extract seperate words - `UPDATE`, `USER`, `ACCOUNT`, `SUCCESS`

Can someone please help me?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a solution to get 3 groups : group 1 = UPDATE, group 2= USER_ACCOUNT, group 3 = SUCCESS

`([A-Z]+)+_+([A-Z]+)+_+(SUCCESS|FAILURE)+`

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
read -a arr < <(xmllint --xpath '/event/id/text()' file | tr '_' ' ')
printf '%s\n' ${arr[@]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this regex to filter your text:

```
>([^<>]+)<
```

Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/wM9rX4/1

Python code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'>([^<>]+)<')
test_str = u"<event><id>UPDATE_USER_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS_APP</id></event> "

re.search(p, test_str)
```

And then split it by '_'

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'_')
test_str = u"UPDATE_USER_ACCOUNT_SUCCESS_APP"

re.split(p, test_str)
```

Also, if you don't want to use Python, or any other programming language, you can use these regexes in text editors, like Notepad++, if you are in Windows.

For example, in Notepad++, you can use this regex in replace menu, after activating regexes.